# How to identify points on black polygon using javacv/opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, javacv

I try to identify Contour around this black polygon and I need to access those points but it doesn't work for me. This is the input image 
[image]

But when I try to do following code It didn't gave the expected result which means it should.

```
        CanvasFrame cnvs=new CanvasFrame("Polygon");
        cnvs.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CvMemStorage storage=CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSeq squares = new CvContour();
        squares = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvContour.class), sizeof(CvSeq.class), storage);
        String path="project/Test/img/black.png";
        IplImage src = cvLoadImage(path);
        IplImage gry=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
        cvCvtColor(src, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(gry, gry, 230, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        cnvs.showImage(gry);
        cvFindContours(gry, storage, squares, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        CvSeq ss=null;
        CvSeq tmp=null;
        int ii=0;
            for (ss=squares; ss!=null; ss=ss.h_next()) {
                tmp=cvApproxPoly(ss, sizeof(CvContour.class), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 8, 0);
                System.out.println("index "+ii+" points "+tmp.total()+" area "+cvContourArea(ss, CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0));
                cvDrawContours(src, ss, CvScalar.RED, CV_RGB(248, 18, 18), 1, -1, 8);
                //drawPoly(src, tmp);
            }
        IplConvKernel mat=cvCreateStructuringElementEx(7, 7, 3, 3, CV_SHAPE_RECT, null);
        cvDilate(src, src, mat, CV_C);
        cvErode(src, src, mat, CV_C);
        cnvs.showImage(src);
        saveImage("nw.png", src);
```

But when I check the out put it gives only

index 0 points 8 area 20179.0

That means it only identify 8 points of the polygon but it should be 12 points.
Please can some one explain problem of this code.

This show the out put image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cvApproxPoly() function uses [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm for curve approximation. The purpose of the algorithm is to find a similar curve with fewer points. The algorithm itself takes two parameters as input:

- list of points (vertices),
- aproximation accuracy.

Briefly, the greater the aproximation acuracy value, the bigger chance to the point being omitted in aproximated curve (please refer to the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), especially [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDouglas-Peucker_animated.gif) animation). In your function call:

```
cvApproxPoly(ss, sizeof(CvContour.class), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 8, 0);
```

the 5th parameter is the aproximation accuracy. If you don't want to reduce number of vertices the value should be small (for this example values around 1 give exactly 12 vertices, therefore no approximation).